# Rails - Jquery UI Slider - Showing slider value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, slider

I've had some difficulties getting `Jquery UI Slider` functionality working in Ruby on Rails.

I have managed to get the slider bar showing and have assigned values to it. The problem is, the value of the slider isn't shown.

**Application.js**

```
 $(function() {
   $( "#slider" ).slider({
     min: 400,
     max: 2400,
     value: 1500,
     animate: "slow",
     orientation: "horizontal",
     slide: function(event, ui) {
       $("#price").val(ui.value);
     }
   });
 });
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag Product.new do |f| %>

  <%= label_tag :price %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :price %>

<% end %>
```

Here is the HTML output of this code

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/components" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="pfd9cKHWlEm/xdJmsegoc20CSFWLfQcbkbva27B/SgQ=" /></div>

<label for="price">Price</label>
<input id="price" name="price" type="hidden" />

</form><div id="slider"></div>
```

I used this website as a guide to generate the following code

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
  $("#price").val(ui.value);
}
```

I understood that the `slide` event is triggered on all mouse moves. I entered the above code and it the value of the slider still does not appear.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value isn't shown because the input field type is 'hidden', please use a 'text' field instead,

The updated value can be checked in the developer console through console.log():

`slide: function(event, ui) {
  console.log(ui.value);
  $("#price").val(ui.value);
}`

I hope that helps.